How can I make these checkboxes and labels Inline
I tried to make them inline by changing their display to inline-flex and item-align to borderline but it dosent work.


input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border-color: #4caf50;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::after {
  content: "✓";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: -2px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
<main>
  <h1 id="title">Survey form</h1>
  <p id="description">
    Thank you for taking time to help us improving this site
  </p>
  <div class="imp">
    <form id="survey-form">

      <fieldset>
        <div>
          <label for="question">Would you use this website in future?<br />
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="yes"
                  name="question"
                  id="question"
                  checked
                />Yes
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  value="no"
                  name="question"
                  id="question"
                />No
              </label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
          <input type="checkbox" value="Anime" id="best-part-anime" name="best-part" />
          <label for="best-part-anime">Anime streaming in 4K quality</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
          <input type="checkbox" value="Manga" id="best-part-manga" name="best-part" />
          <label for="best-part-manga">Manga in HD quality</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
          <input type="checkbox" value="Torrent" id="best-part-torrent" name="best-part" />
          <label for="best-part-torrent">Torrent streaming</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox-container">
          <input type="checkbox" value="Other" id="best-part-other" name="best-part" />
          <label for="best-part-other">Other</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="Other">(Please specify your problen in certain or any other feedback)
                <textarea
                  id="other"
                  name="other"
                  value="other"
                  placeholder="Tell us more about your problem"
                ></textarea>
              </label>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</main>



pls help me when inspect to do so it works but after i do same(what i edit there) in vs code it dosent work....
I want to make the labels and checkboxes appear in same line... but I can't figure out what's wrong here

There is no item-align: borderline property/value.

BTW, your HTML is invalid - you have a <label for="question"> which encloses two separate <input type="radio"> elements, with duplicate id="" attributes.

To make the labels and checkboxes appear on the same line, you need to adjust the CSS for both the label and the input elements. Since you're using absolute positioning for the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements, you'll also need to adjust the positioning context for them.


.checkbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; 
  position: relative; 
  line-height: 30px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none; 
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  border-color: #4caf50;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::after {
  content: "✓";
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); 
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
<main>
    <h1 id="title">Survey form</h1>
    <p id="description">
        Thank you for taking time to help us improving this site
    </p>
    <div class="imp">
        <form id="survey-form">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label for="question">
                        Would you use this website in future?<br />
                        <input type="radio" value="yes" name="question" id="question" checked />Yes <input type="radio" value="no" name="question" id="question" />No
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Anime" id="best-part-anime" name="best-part" />
                    <label for="best-part-anime">Anime streaming in 4K quality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Manga" id="best-part-manga" name="best-part" />
                    <label for="best-part-manga">Manga in HD quality</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Torrent" id="best-part-torrent" name="best-part" />
                    <label for="best-part-torrent">Torrent streaming</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox-container">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Other" id="best-part-other" name="best-part" />
                    <label for="best-part-other">Other</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="Other">
                        (Please specify your problen in certain or any other feedback)
                        <textarea id="other" name="other" value="other" placeholder="Tell us more about your problem"></textarea>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>



